# Trying to match word combinations with variations in between

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to match a word combination that has other words between it.

For example, trying to match "beer glasses" when other words are between them both.

I know I could do \bbeer (.+) glasses\b but is there a more precise way to do it, that would omit any in between words?

Comment: Are you trying to match anythng between two whole words? Then use `\bbeer\b(.*?)\bglasses\b`. Or `\bbeer\b\s*(.*?)\s*\bglasses\b`. Or `\bbeer\s+(.*?)\s+glasses\b`. Or even `\bbeer\s+((?s:.*?))\s+glasses\b`.

Comment: Can you provide examples of "in between words" that you would like to "omit"? Do you mean you don't want to capture the inbetween stuff? `(\bbeer\b)(?:.*?)(\bglasses\b)` ? What problem are you trying to solve?